# Anonymous Access to SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

We're looking to have a RaspberryPi run in kiosk mode and automatically pull up a report on our SSRS portal without any user interaction.

I'm hoping I can allow anonymous access to this specific report and keep Active Directory authentication in place for our other reports/folders.

I've added "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" to the report security without any luck.

Is what I'm looking to do possible?

We're running MSSQL 2019.

Comment: Yep.  But the title of that article is misleading.  That's not anonymous.  It's HTTP Basic Auth passing Windows Credentials, which is a supported auth method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/authentication-with-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15  It's disabled by default because the report server sees the plaintext password, so it's less secure than NTLM or Kerberos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating as someone asked me to post as answer.

I found a work around. This isn't Anonymous Authentication, but uses HTTP Basic Authentication to pass Windows Credentials to SSRS

This is the guide I used:
https://tickett.wordpress.com/2014/12/03/anonymous-authentication-sql-server-reporting-services/?unapproved=9854&moderation-hash=4bf90332f3468fc8b78f6b84e1e63d6d#comment-9854

I found I had to use this tool instead of the one they suggested (http://www.swingnote.com/tools/texttohex.php) and used "Hex Encoded for URL"

In case that website isn't accessible, here's a step by step process outlined in the original article.

Create this file below to put at the root of your SSRS web server or another IIS server at this location:`C:\inetpub\wwwroot`. Give it a unique name so you can remember the URL and save it as a .html file (let's call it `your_report.html` for this example.) **Make sure to read the comments in the code**

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script>

// use this website to convert a user account and password to view reports into hex (https://www.swingnote.com/tools/texttohex.php)
// Do not use your domain as the prefix, just an AD user name. Best practice would be to create an account that only has read privileges to this report only 
// use hex encoded for URL for this
//       First section is the username     |   Second section is the password

var _0x1751=["\x61\x66","\x76\x76"];

function getHTTPObject() {
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    return false;
}   

function runReport() {
  var http = getHTTPObject();


// Here is the section for the report you want to use
  var url= "http://<your_report_server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?<report_name>&rs:Command=Render";
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
      if (http.status == 401) {
        runReport(); 
      }
      if (http.status == 200) {
        document.location = url;
      }
    }
  };
  http.open("get", url, true, _0x1751[0x0], _0x1751[0x1]);
  http.send(null);
  return false;
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="runReport();">
  </body>
</html>
```

After the file is saved to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, test it by going to your report server (`http://<report_server_name>/your_report.html`)

Comment: Im a bit confused this did not work for me. Do i need to install IIS?  I have ssrs installed but i dont see a c:\inetpub folder did you manually create that?  Do i need to install windows iis feature on the ssrs report server?

Comment: Jon, yeah you might need to setup IIS if it isn't already installed.

Answer (score -1):

The most helpful article I've found to accomplish what you're requesting is [Setting up Anonymous Access for Reporting Services in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://www.swarndeep.com/2011/12/setting-up-anonymous-access-for.html) by Swarndeep Singh:

> - Change the authentication mode in rsreportserver.config to Custom
> - Change the Authentication mode in web.config file in ReportServer to None. Also change the Impersonation to false.
> - Compile the code from this location to bin folder as Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.AnonymousSecurity.dll Or copy it from this location and paste it to bin folder in ReportServer.
> - Add Extensions in rsreportserver.config
> - Add the additional extension in Security Tag
> - Add the following codegroup to configure the code access security in rssrvpolicy.config
>
> ```xml
> <CodeGroup
> class="UnionCodeGroup"
> version="1"
> PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
> Name="Private_assembly"
> Description="This code group grants custom code full trust. ">
> <IMembershipCondition
> class="UrlMembershipCondition"
> version="1"
> Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.AnonymousSecurity.dll"
> />
> </CodeGroup>
> ```
>
> Restart the reporting services, Anonymous Access should work.